# Problem width wp_insert_post_data and Gutenberg block editor

Tags: filters, block-editor

I need to change the post title of a Custom Post Type before save it. I have try with wp_insert_post_data filter and works fine. The problem is that normal posts that uses Gutenberg fires an error "the response is not a valid JSON response" when save it although it's not applied the filter in this case.

Any suggestions?. Is it possible to fire the wp_insert_post_data filter only width the CPT that uses it. Actually the filter is launched always and is necessary check the post type to make the action.

I have found some information pointed to the REST API mechanism that Gutenberg uses but without any conclusions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you edit your question to include the code? It's very difficult if not impossible to help from just a description

Comment: Can you open the inspector in the network panel, and show us the response you get from the Ajax call that is triggering this error? You will probably see an error or some output that shouldn't be there

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.